# can anyone give me the correct way of writing query for this function?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to implement search function where the user can search either of the following: name, age, address, gender, course and year?

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE name LIKE '%name%'
  OR age BETWEEN 'age' AND 'age'
  OR address LIKE '%address%'
  OR gender = 'gender'
  OR course LIKE '%course%'
  OR YEAR = 'year'


Note: each of the search criteria is in different input field
```

but i can't get the correct results whenever the user input either 1 or more of the search criteria.

i know when to use the `OR` and `AND` but I just can't get the correct way of writing query for that.

example is: i have table student.

```
id   name   address   age   gender  course  year

2    juan   New York   19    male   IT      2
4    whitney New Jersey 23    female BA     4
7    manny   Canada     20    male   Law    2

Note: age is a select input field. example is 
15-20
20-25
25-30 and etc.
```

however when I'm trying to search for example is course which is `IT`, it returns all records which is wrong. the correct result should only be related to `IT` like the first record.

Comment: There's not enough information here. How does 'age' differ from 'age'? Either way, this topic must be WIDELY discussed out there on the ether.

Comment: Is age really a string?

Comment: use TRIM if you want to handle 'age' and ' age'

Comment: You should provide sample data and examples of what you want returned.  It may surprise you that non-working queries don't always convey very well what you want to do.

Comment: And, using same value on a field with between clause makes no sense. You can directly use equal to on it. `age between 'age' and 'age'` should be `age = 'age'` or `age between 'age1' and 'age2'`

Comment: @Strawberry age is an integer. I use `between` in age because age is in range. sample is from 5 to 10 and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE name LIKE '%name%'  OR (age > 23 AND age < 30)
OR address LIKE '%address%'  OR gender = 'gender' OR course LIKE '%course%' 
OR YEAR = 'year'
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9aa3/1)